# In Instagram if I block someone will all my comments to him be deleted?

Tags: instagram

In Instagram, if I comment something on a post by someone, and later block him, will all my comments to him be deleted?

Instagram says "After you block someone, their likes and comments will be removed from your photos and videos. Unblocking someone won't restore their previous likes and comments". Instagram does not say about will my comments to him be deleted.

Comment: How to make those comments reappear on my posts after I unblock someone. I had blocked by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Your likes and comments will all disappear from anything associated with that person's account.

Comment: Thanks. Can you find a citation? That is, if Xyz replies to me in a comment in some account, and I replied to him back starting with @Xyz, will that comment get deleted too once I block Xyz? I did not find any documentation of that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will be deleted.Your likes and comments will be disappeared.